# Able to connect to MongoDB running in a Docker container locally, but not from another container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

Basically what the title says: I am able to connect to my MongoDB database running in a Docker container locally, but I am unable to do so from within another Docker container. I am getting the error "MongoError: failed to connect to server {server address}:27017 on first connect"

Here is my config file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

let mongoURI = {
  development: 'mongodb://{server address}:27017/database,
}

const db = mongoose.connect(mongoURI.development, function(err, res) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error connecting to the database. ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to Database: ' + mongoURI.development);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Have you specified the port mapping to be exposed in docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I should have specified this earlier: My configuration was the two containers not linked with the --link option, and MongoDB port exposed. The issue was that my company uses a proxy, and I was not disabling it properly when connecting to a server running on our domain.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your question what configuration of Docker containers you're working with. There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Two Docker containers, one running a MongoDB image and another running your application, linked together via the `--link` option.

Assuming you gave the Mongo container a name via the `--name` option, you should be able to access the MongoDB via the container name: `mongodb://{container name}:27017/database`.

2. Two Docker containers NOT linked with the `--link` option.

In this case, you will need to have exposed the MongoDB port on the Mongo container with the `-p` option AND provided the application container with an IP address of your Docker host: `mongodb://{docker host IP}:27017/database`. Note that `localhost` will **not** work, since inside your application container `localhost` will refer to the application container. You could configure an entry in the application's `/etc/hosts` to give your Docker host a name.

3. MongoDB running in a container; application running on the Docker host (or some other server).

This is just a variation of #2 above. Again, you need to expose the ports and ensure that the application know how to find the host where the MongoDB container is running. In this case you *could* use `localhost` if the application in running on the Docker host.